# How can I create a model with ActiveRecord capabilities but without an actual table behind?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I think this is a recurrent question in the Internet, but unfortunately I'm still unable to find a successful answer.

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to create a model that interfaces with a SQL query, not with an actual table in the database. For example, let's suppose I have two tables in my database: `Questions` and `Answers`. I want to make a report that contains statistics of both tables. For such purpose, I have a complex SQL statement that takes data from these tables to build up the statistics. However the SELECT used in the SQL statement does not directly take values from neither Answers nor Questions tables, but from nested SELECTs.

So far I've been able to create the `StatItem` model, without any migration, but when I try `StatItem.find_by_sql("...nested selects...")` the system complains about unexisting table `stat_items` in the database.

How can I create a model whose instance's data is retrieved from a complex query and not from a table? If it's not possible, I could create a temporary table to store the data in there. In such case, how can I tell the migration file to not create such table (it would be created by the query)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Kohl and his proposal of materialized views has given me an idea, which I initially discarded because I wrongly thought that a single database connection could be shared by two processes, but after reading about how Rails processes requests, I think my solution is fine.

**STEP 1 - Create the model without migration**

```
rails g model StatItem --migration=false
```

**STEP 2 - Create a temporary table called `stat_items`**

```
#First, drop any existing table created by older requests (database connections are kept open by the server process(es).
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stat_items')

#Second, create the temporary table with the desired columns (notice: a dummy column called 'id:integer' should exist in the table)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('CREATE TEMP TABLE stat_items (id integer, ...)')
```

**STEP 3 - Execute an SQL statement that inserts rows in `stat_items`**

**STEP 4 - Access the table using the model, as usual**

For example:

```
StatItem.find_by_...
```

Any comments/improvements are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a materialized view from your complex query and following this tutorial:

[ActiveRecord + PostgreSQL Materialized Views](http://eng.wolox.com.ar/blog/2014/07/28/activerecord-plus-postgresql-materialized-views/)

Comment: That's brilliant. Unfortunately I'm using a PosgreSQL 9.1 server. However I give you a +1 because you've inspired the answer I'm writing right now.

Comment: Damn... My idea was to create a temporary table called `stat_items` before calling StatItem methods... It works, but not as expected because the database session is kept open by Rails and a concurrent client cannot create the table because it already exists...

Comment: BTW, couldn't an ordinary view be a solution for my problem? I didn't think about that...

Comment: Glad it helped a bit at least. And yes, any view will do.